# Shifting indexes - timer based

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I haven't used `UITabBarController` much before. Hence asking the question. After loading a view I want to show a label named `Row1` in `tab 1` after 5 seconds, then after 5 more seconds i.e 10 seconds again want to show a label named `Row1` in `tab 2` and after 5 more seconds i.e 15 seconds I want to again show a label named `Row1` in tab 3. Then after 20 seconds the tab 1 will show both `Row 1` and `Row 2`. Then after 25 seconds the tab 2 will show both `Row 1` and `Row 2`. Then after 30 seconds the tab 3 will show both `Row 1` and `Row 2`.

Comment: and when does this weird disco dance end?

Comment: it should go on...:)@staticVoidMan

Comment: fun homework you got there :D

Comment: so... how did it go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the steps

1. Subclass the `UITabbarController`
2. In the `ViewDidLoad` of the subclassed `UITabbarController` start a `Timer` to do your timely job.
3. To switch the tab use `selectedIndex` when time comes.

[Here](https://github.com/ratulSharker/AutoChanging-Tabbar) is a initial project, where you can start.

Comment: oh..and how do I subclass `UITabbarController `..?@Ratul Sharker

Comment: Stackoverflow is no tutorial site. we can only show you the path, you have to walk it yourself.

Comment: .@Ratul Sharker I tried something like so to get the selectedIndex. But it doesn't seem to work...`var sf = MyChangingTabController()
            sf.selectedIndex = 2`

Comment: I have provided a small project which covers most of your requirement. If you understand the steps, then marking the answer as accepted and upvoting the answer will motivate us to keep answering question. Thank you

Comment: I didn't notice that @Ratul...Thanks..:)have given anupvote too..:)

Comment: just a concern @Ratul..how would I configure for the 3rd tab..?

Comment: it's cumbersome to describe, better watch video https://youtu.be/yzImO9HdbFo?t=275

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168996/discussion-between-ratul-sharker-and-v-bw).